# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio window pops up on top after wake-up from sleep

Tags: windows

When MS SQL Server Management Studio is open (and in the background), the window pops up on wake-up from sleep. If another window was on top and even if Management Studio was minimized, it still pops up on top of all other windows. How can this irritating behavior be prevented?

EDIT:
I am using SQL Server Express 2014 on Window 10, but it was the same with older versions of SQL Server Express on Windows 7.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:     12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools:   12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC):    10.0.10586.0
Microsoft MSXML:                            3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer:                9.11.10586.0
Microsoft .NET Framework:                   4.0.30319.42000
Operating System:                           6.3.10586

Comment: Which version of SSMS? Which service pack/rollup?

Comment: This is an abnormal behaviour and shouldn't happen. Reinstall? also check the logs for more info.

Comment: I did upgrade to Windows 10, and I installed the new version of SQL Server Express. Are you sure this doesn't happen on your system too? Strange.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version is 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Does this have a solution? I have this issue with SSMS 2012 (11.0.3156.0) on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 and I would really like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Here we are in 2024 and it's happening to me (SSMS 2022 developer edition)